# Wrong 2nd argument type: Found: 'com.google.android.youtube.player.YoutubePlayerFragment'

Tags: android

Wrong 2nd argument type: Found: `com.google.android.youtube.player.YoutubePlayerFragment`, required: `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Image below is the error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;.


import com.ggcutie.computersystemservicingcss.youtube.PlayerConfig;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment;


public class COC1_Lesson1_1_Watch extends Fragment implements 
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.coc1_lesson_1_1_fragment2_activity, container, false);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youtubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    youtubePlayerFragment.initialize(PlayerConfig.getApiKey(), this);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtube_player_fragment, youtubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return v;

}


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if (!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("EJylz_9KYf8");
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
```

This is my FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
 import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class COC1_Lesson1_1_ViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

public COC1_Lesson1_1_ViewPager(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new COC1_Lesson1_1_Learn();
        case 1:
            return new COC1_Lesson1_1_Watch();
        case 2:
            return new COC1_Lesson1_1_Do();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}
public void add(Fragment fr,String str){
    fragments.add(fr);
    strings.add(str);
}
@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return strings.get(position);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` code? Might be that you're missing import statements for Fragment if you extend that class from Fragment correctly.

Comment: Please see my codes above. Thank you in advance! I hope you can help me.